# How to read first few rows from CSV using univocity parser

Tags: univocity

How to stop parsing after reading few rows from CSV file using iterator/row processor in univocity parser?

Update #1

I tried the below code and I'm getting empty rows.

```
val parserSettings = new CsvParserSettings
parserSettings.detectFormatAutomatically()
parserSettings.setEmptyValue("")
parserSettings.setNumberOfRecordsToRead(numberOfRecordsToRead)

val parser = new CsvParser(parserSettings)
val input = new FileInputStream(path)
val rows = parser.parseAll(input)
```

Update #2

Before passing inputstream to parser, I was using Apache Tika to detect the MIME type of the file to detect whether the file is CSV.

`new Tika().detect(input)`

This was altering the inputstream. Due to that Univocity parser was unable to parse correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have many different options:

1. From your row processor just call `context.stop()`.
2. On the parser settings, you can set `settings.setNumberOfRecordsToRead(10)` to read 10 rows and stop.
3. With the parser itself, call `parser.stopParsing()`

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Updated the question with answer based on your solution no.2.(Update #1). Not working. Am I missing something?

Comment: It should work just fine. In all tests I ran the `rows` returned by the parser have at most the number of records set in the configuration. Are you using the latest version?

Comment: Yes, using `2.5.9`

Comment: Very weird. Can you submit a sample of the input you are trying to parse so I can try to reproduce this?

Comment: I created a sample project and tested the functionality. It works. Find out the cause of the issue and updated in question(Update #2). Thank you for your time.

Comment: There is one issue. Even after using `setEmptyValue("")`, null is returned for missing values in a cell.  [Sample Code](https://gist.github.com/gowravshekar/f19170e52148e17f4b20e4ec4f829f3d). Last cells of row 8 & 9.

Comment: I believe you are looking for `setNullValue("")`.